# Handle either a list or single integer as an argument

Tags: python, list, function, integer

A function should select rows in a table based on the row name (column 2 in this case). It should be able to take either a single name or a list of names as arguments and handle them correctly.

This is what I have now, but ideally there wouldn't be this duplicated code and something like exceptions would be used intelligently to choose the right way to handle the input argument:

```
def select_rows(to_select):
    # For a list
    for row in range(0, table.numRows()):
        if _table.item(row, 1).text() in to_select:
            table.selectRow(row)
    # For a single integer
    for row in range(0, table.numRows()):
        if _table.item(row, 1).text() == to_select:
            table.selectRow(row)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Actually I agree with [Andrew Hare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/998949/3357935), just pass a list with a single element.

But if you really must accept a non-list, how about just turning it into a list in that case?

```
def select_rows(to_select):
    if type(to_select) is not list: to_select = [ to_select ]

    for row in range(0, table.numRows()):
        if _table.item(row, 1).text() in to_select:
            table.selectRow(row)
```

The performance penalty for doing 'in' on a single-item list isn't likely to be high :-)
But that does point out one other thing you might want to consider doing if your 'to_select' list may be long: consider casting it to a set so that lookups are more efficient.

```
def select_rows(to_select):
    if type(to_select) is list: to_select = set( to_select )
    elif type(to_select) is not set: to_select = set( [to_select] )

    for row in range(0, table.numRows()):
        if _table.item(row, 1).text() in to_select:
            table.selectRow(row)
```

Comment: It is currently considered better to use `isinstance` rather than `type`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance

Comment: And if using `isinstance`, there are 2/3-compatibility concerns for certain types. For example, string types are str (in 3) or basestring (in 2.7). You can use `six.string_types` or `six.integer_types` for this. Unfortunately, there's no `six.float_types` so if you need `long` from Python 2.7 you'll have to code that manually.

Answer (score 29):

You could redefine your function to take any number of arguments, like this:

```
def select_rows(*arguments):
    for row in range(0, table.numRows()):
        if _table.item(row, 1).text() in arguments:
            table.selectRow(row)
```

Then you can pass a single argument like this:

```
select_rows('abc')
```

multiple arguments like this:

```
select_rows('abc', 'def')
```

And if you already have a list:

```
items = ['abc', 'def']
select_rows(*items)
```

Comment: +1 Like this approach better than Andrew Hare's... Problem could be if you needed to pass more arguments to the same function, not just the list/single argument. But you could either have those before, or use keyword arguments, i.e. **kwargs.

Comment: This answer is clearly better.
+1 Self-documenting code. *args begs for an iterable.

Answer (score 12):

I would do just this:

```
def select_rows(to_select):
    # For a list
    for row in range(0, table.numRows()):
        if _table.item(row, 1).text() in to_select:
            table.selectRow(row)
```

and expect that the argument will always be a list - even if its just a list of one element.

Remember:

> It is easier to ask for forgiveness than permission.

Comment: +1... much easier to maintain just one set of code to performs a task, and more pythonic; let it explode if someone calls it in defiance of the docs. If a function is truly needed that accepts a single integer as an argument, make a second one called 'def select_row(to_select)' and have it package 'to_select' as a list, then call select_rows.

Comment: @JarretHardie : "let it explode if someone calls it in defiance of the docs" ... as a refugee from C#, I find this attitude in python programming the most befuddling :-D

Answer (score 2):

I'd go along with Sharkey's version, but use a bit more duck typing:

```
def select_rows(to_select):
    try:
        len(to_select)
    except TypeError:
        to_select = [to_select]

    for row in range(0, table.numRows()):
        if _table.item(row, 1).text() in to_select:
            table.selectRow(row)
```

This has the benefit of working with any object that supports the in operator.  Also, the previous version, if given a tuple or some other sequence, would just wrap it in a list.  The downside is that there is some performance penalty for using exception handling.

Comment: This one is problematic for unicodes and strings.  cf:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305359/correct-way-to-detect-sequence-parameter/425567#425567

Comment: Valid point, should at least have been "in (list, tuple)" ... or maybe "not in (string, unicode)".

Preferably you'd want to look directly for "does this thingy support 'in'", I suppose.

Comment: Actually, Python doesn't really have a performance penalty for exception handling like other languages.  See, for instance: https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

A simple wrapper could do, to handle list or single object case

```
  def wrap_list(val):
    if type(val) is list:
      return val
    return [val]
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit less general but concise, using numpy:

```
numpy.unique()
```

handles that automatically by keeping only the unique values of an array-like or scalar, and returns a list of the unique values, or of the scalar.

```
import numpy as np

def select_rows(to_select):
   to_select = np.unique(to_select)

   for row in range(0, table.numRows()):
       if _table.item(row, 1).text() in to_select:
           table.selectRow(row)
```