# Iterating over list or single element in python

Tags: python

I would like to iterate over the outputs of an unknown function. Unfortunately I do not know whether the function returns a single item or a tuple. This must be a standard problem and there must be a standard way of dealing with this -- what I have now is quite ugly.

```
x = UnknownFunction()
if islist(x):
    iterator = x
else:
    iterator = [x]

def islist(s):
    try:
        len(s)
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False

for ii in iterator:
    #do stuff
```

Comment: The standard way is to have the function return a 1-tuple.

Comment: @Ignacio: Sure, if you have control over that function. The question seems to be saying that he does not.

Comment: @Fred Larson: You always do have at least that much control: `lambda *a, **kw: (f(*a, **kw), )`.

Comment: @Rosh, then you have to test whether the result is nested in a tuple or not.

Comment: @senderle: Hopefully there would be some level at which the function is known and can be wrapped. I haven't seen unpredictable APIs yet. ;)

Comment: @Rosh The name of the function to call is provided by the user, so the form of the result is not known until run time.

Comment: @Rosh, quite so, wrapping is the way to go, I didn't mean to disagree with you there.

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998938/handle-either-a-list-or-single-integer-as-an-argument

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The most general solution to this problem is to use `isinstance` with the abstract base class `collections.Iterable`.

```
import collections

def get_iterable(x):
    if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
        return x
    else:
        return (x,)
```

You might also want to test for `basestring` as well, as [Kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710834/iterating-over-list-or-single-element-in-python/6710895#6710895) suggests.

```
    if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(x, basestring):
```

Now some people might think, as I once did, "isn't `isinstance` [considered harmful](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/)? Doesn't it lock you into using one kind of type? Wouldn't using `hasattr(x, '__iter__')` be better?"

The answer is: not when it comes to abstract base classes. In fact, you can define your own class with an `__iter__` method and it will be recognized as an instance of `collections.Iterable`, *even if you do not subclass* `collections.Iterable`. This works because `collections.Iterable` defines a [`__subclasshook__`](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__) that determines whether a type passed to it is an Iterable by whatever definition it implements.

```
>>> class MyIter(object):
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return iter(range(10))
... 
>>> i = MyIter()
>>> isinstance(i, collections.Iterable)
True
>>> collections.Iterable.__subclasshook__(type(i))
True
```

Comment: Note also that you could test for `collections.Sequence` if you want to only include list- and tuple- like types.

Comment: I also get `isinstance('aa',collections.Iterable)` as `True` which is not what I was expecting. Is there a tweak?

Comment: @Dinesh, True is the correct thing to return -- a string is an Iterable of characters! If you want your code to behave differently for strings, you have to add a test. Use isinstance(x, basestring) to capture both strings and unicode objects.

Comment: Using or importing the ABCs (like `Iterable`) from `collections` instead of from `collections.abc` is deprecated since Python 3.3,and in 3.9 it will stop working. Use `from collections.abc import Iterable` instead.

Comment: @Michele quite so. This is out-of-date in several ways — `basestring` doesn't exist in Python 3 at all! I'll update it when I can but feel free to edit if you like.

Answer (score 7):

It's not particularly elegant to include the code everywhere you need it.  So write a function that does the massaging.  Here's a suggestion I came up with for a similar previous question.  It special-cases strings (which would usually be iterable) as single items, which is what I find I usually want.

```
def iterfy(iterable):
    if isinstance(iterable, basestring):
        iterable = [iterable]
    try:
        iter(iterable)
    except TypeError:
        iterable = [iterable]
    return iterable
```

Usage:

```
for item in iterfy(unknownfunction()):
     # do something
```

**Update** Here's a generator version that uses the new-ish (Python 3.3) `yield from` statement.

```
def iterfy(iterable):
    if isinstance(iterable, str):
        yield iterable
    else:
        try:
            # need "iter()" here to force TypeError on non-iterable
            # as e.g. "yield from 1" doesn't throw until "next()"
            yield from iter(iterable)
        except TypeError:
            yield iterable
```

Comment: I somehow like the name `iterrify` better. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps better to use `collections.Iterable` to find out whether the output is an iterable or not.

```
import collections

x = UnknownFunction()
if not isinstance(x, collections.Iterable): x = [x]

for ii in x:
    #do stuff
```

This will work if type of x is either of these - `list`, `tuple`, `dict`, `str`, any class derived from these.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do the following:

```
iterator = (x,) if not isinstance(x, (tuple, list)) else x
```

then

```
for i in iterator:
    #do stuff
```

Comment: That doesn't work with tuples (mentioned in the question). It doesn't work with subclasses of list either.

Comment: You should probably have: iterator = (x,) if type(x) != tuple else x

Comment: `not isinstance(x, cls)` would almost always be preferable to `type(x) != cls`

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. How come? (I'll change it in the answer.)

Comment: @TorelTwiddler: By comparing with the class directly, you're excluding all subclasses. E.g. that won't work with named tuples.

Comment: This is correct in answering my question -- is there simple syntax that simultaneously checks whether it x is a tuple or a list, though?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer with it. `(x,) if not isinstance(x, (tuple,list)) else x`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the operator.isSequenceType function

```
import operator
x = unknown_function()
if not operator.isSequenceType(x) and not isinstance(x, basestring):
    x = (x,)
for item in x:
    do_something(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might define a function that ensures the returned value supports iteration (`str`, `dict`, `tuple`, etc --including user-defined sequence types that don't directly inherit from these classes) rather than checking if it is a `tuple` or `list` directly.

```
def ensure_iterable(x):
    return (x,) if not hasattr(x, '__iter__') else x

x = ensure_iterable(UnknownFunction())
for i in x:
    do_something(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get better performance if you use generators. This should work on python 3.3 and above.

```
from collections import Iterable

def iterrify(obj):
    """
    Generator yielding the passed object if it's a single element or
    yield all elements in the object if the object is an iterable.

    :param obj: Single element or iterable.
    """
    if isinstance(obj, (str, bytes)):  # Add any iterables you want to threat as single elements here
        yield obj
    elif isinstance(obj, Iterable):  # Yield from the iterables.
        yield from obj
    else:  # yield single elements as is.
        yield obj
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach with Itreable [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6711233/1950100) by someone else. Though maybe in some cases the following would be better. It is more more EAFP (https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp) way:

```
In [10]: def make_iter(x): 
    ...:         try: 
    ...:             return iter(x) 
    ...:         except TypeError: 
    ...:             # We seem to be dealing with something that cannot be itereated over. 
    ...:             return iter((x,)) 
    ...:              

In [11]: make_iter(3)                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[11]: <tuple_iterator at 0x7fa367b29590>

In [13]: make_iter((3,))                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[13]: <tuple_iterator at 0x7fa367b4cad0>

In [14]: make_iter([3])                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[14]: <list_iterator at 0x7fa367b29c90>
```

This doesn't bothers with checking what we are dealing with. We just try to get an iterator and if it fails, we assume it failed because we were dealing with something that cannot be iterated over (well, it really seems like it cannot be). So we just make a tuple and make an iterator from that.