# How to iterate a list of filepaths or just one element filepath

Tags: python, list

I have a working code that takes a list of file paths and reads them iteratively. For example:

```
class moveDcmNrrd4mJson_v3(object):
  def __init__(self, jsonList, dataPath, dframe):
     self.jsonList = jsonList #providing a list
     self.dataPath = dataPath
     self.dframe = dframe

  def MoveFiles(self):
     for jsonidx, jsonpath in enumerate(self.jsonList):
        print("\n")
        print(">>> Reading {} of {} json file: {}".format(jsonidx+1, len(self.jsonList), os.path.basename(jsonpath)))
```

That works when more than one file paths are in the list.
for example when:
`['/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1053.json',   '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1418.json',   '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1452.json',   '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1517.json',   '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1705.json']`

I want to make it work when only single filepath. For example when I call `jsonList[-1]` with the same `enumerate` loop. Now the loop just iterate over the path ASCII characters.

Calling the code as:

```
A = moveDcmNrrd4mJson_v3(jsonList[2], capDir, df) # only one filepath
A.MoveFiles()
```

I have seen some suggestions here in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710834/iterating-over-list-or-single-element-in-python#:%7E:text=import%20collections%0A%0Adef%20get_iterable(x)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20isinstance(x%2C%20collections.Iterable)%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20x%0A%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(x%2C)) however not exactly clear to me.

Comment: If you have a single path, make it a single-element list and iterate over it.

Comment: could you demonstrate? `list(jsonList[-3])` just counts the character numbers. Are there anything called `islist`?

Comment: it depends on how you call the function. please also paste caller code.

Comment: @LeiYang I have expanded the ques, hopefully, it addresses better what I want.

Comment: please paste caller code when you have only one filename.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you may be passing the single path in as a string instead of a list. Make sure it is being passed as a list. If this doesn't answer it for you, could you share a little more about the jsonList?

Comment: Please do not post comments and questions as answers.

Comment: `['/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1053.json',
  '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1418.json',
  '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1452.json',
  '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1517.json',
  '/media/banikr2/CAP_Exam_Data0/CAP Session Backups/wilist_all_MV_20180914-1705.json']`

This is the `jsonList` with 5 filepaths which works in my code. But I want to make it work for a single path like `jsonList[2]` which is a `str` I know.

Comment: @DYZ, if he is in fact passing the single path as a string, is it not the answer (or really one of many answers)? Would it have been more acceptable if I left out the last sentence hedging my answer?
banikr, is there a reason to not simply convert your single string to a list?

Comment: I don't know why the question was closed without clarification. This is passing a string of filepath but the other question is just numbers which is two different thing

Comment: @banikr It _is_ the same thing. A list of one number is constructed exactly like a list of one string.

Comment: banikr, some people here are too smart to realize that everything is not so obvious without years of experience. If there is a reason the single file path must always come in as a string, I would suggest putting a simple if statement ahead of your print statement to convert it to a single item list <<if type(jsonList) == str:>> (next line) <<jsonList = [jsonList]>>. This should allow your code to function the way it is currently written. I guarantee you there's a better way of doing it, but I'm not the smartest guy here, just trying to get you something that works.