# Best way to iterate over variable that can be a single object or list/iterator of objects

Tags: python

Suppose I have a Python function that takes in an argument that can either be, e.g., an `int` or list of `int`s and I want to loop over that argument:

```py
from typing import List, Union


def myfunc(arg: Union[int, List[int]]) -> List[int]:
    x = []
    for value in arg:
        x.append(2 * value)

    return x
```

Now, obviously this will work if you do give it a list, but will fail with a `TypeError` if you give it an `int` because an `int` is not an iterable object.

In these situations I generally do something like:

```py
def myfunc(arg: Union[int, List[int]]) -> List[int]:
    x = []
    arglist = arg if isinstance(arg, list) else [arg]
    for value in arglist:
        x.append(2 * value)

    return x
```

i.e., I put `arg` into a list if it is not a list and then iterate over that list.

I could instead create a function or class that will convert an object into a list/iterable if it isn't already one, e.g.,

```py
def make_iterator(x):
    try:
        for v in x:
            yield v
    except TypeError:
        yield x


def myfunc(arg: Union[int, List[int]]) -> List[int]:
    x = []
    for value in make_iterator(arg):
        x.append(2 * value)

    return x
```

but I wondered if there is some Python built-in function or standard library module that already exists to do this?

Comment: no, there is no standard library approach. both of these are pretty reasonable approaches, I like the `make_iterator` better, personally, because it is more general. I will say, a function that can accept different a union of types is generally to be avoided, although, it is not as bad as a function that returns a union.

Comment: See also [Iterating over list or single element in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6710834/11082165), which is a more direct duplicate