# How to distinguish between a sequence and a mapping

Tags: python, dictionary, sequence

I would like to perform an operation on an argument based on the fact that it might be a map-like object or a sequence-like object. I understand that no strategy is going to be 100% reliable for type-like checking, but I'm looking for a robust solution.

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305359/correct-way-to-detect-sequence-parameter/425567#425567), I know how to determine whether something is a sequence and I can do this check after checking if the object is a map.

```
def ismap(arg):
   # How to implement this?

def isseq(arg):
   return hasattr(arg,"__iter__")

def operation(arg):
   if ismap(arg):
      # Do something with a dict-like object
   elif isseq(arg):
      # Do something with a sequence-like object
   else:
      # Do something else
```

Because a sequence can be seen as a map where keys are integers, should I just try to find a key that is not an integer? Or maybe I could look at the string representation? or...?

**UPDATE**

I selected SilentGhost's answer because it looks like the most "correct" one, but for my needs, here is the solution I ended up implementing:

```
if hasattr(arg, 'keys') and hasattr(arg, '__getitem__'):
   # Do something with a map
elif hasattr(arg, '__iter__'):
   # Do something with a sequence/iterable
else:
   # Do something else
```

Essentially, I don't want to rely on an ABC because there are many custom classes that behave like sequences and dictionary but that still do not extend the python collections ABCs (see @Manoj comment). I thought the keys attribute (mentioned by someone who removed his/her answer) was a good enough check for mappings.

Classes extending the Sequence and Mapping ABCs will work with this solution as well.

Comment: Why not just try something sequence like or map like, and based on the errors, you can determine what to treat it as.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Mapping, Sequence
>>> isinstance('ac', Sequence)
True
>>> isinstance('ac', Mapping)
False
>>> isinstance({3:42}, Mapping)
True
>>> isinstance({3:42}, Sequence)
False
```

[`collections` abstract base classes (ABCs)](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#abcs-abstract-base-classes)

Comment: How about custom classes? For e.g. Django's `QuerySet`? It behaves like a sequence but `isinstance(a_queryset, Sequence)` returns `False`.

Comment: @Manoj: they might need to fix inheritance? In what sense does it "behave like a sequence"?

Comment: @SilentGhost: Hmmm. You are right. I guess designers will have to start by subclassing the appropriate type if they expect such operations.

Comment: @SilentGhost: I didn't down vote you! In fact I did the opposite :)

Comment: @SilentGhost: you can iterate over a queryset; it can be indexed (positive indexes only); it supports `len`.

Comment: @Manoj: I still would be interested in what you meant by "behaves like a sequence". The docs have a table describing what it means to be an instance of each ABC.

Comment: @Manoj: does it support `.index` and `.count` methods?

Comment: @SilentGhost: `.count()`: yes. `.index()`: no.

Comment: The downvote was me, but I changed my mind. It's a good answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

Sequences have an `__add__` method that implements the + operator. Maps do not have that method, since adding to a map requires both a key and a value, and the + operator only has one right-hand side.

So you may try:

```
def ismap(arg):
    return isseq(arg) and not hasattr(arg, "__add__")
```