# How to make a file-like class work with "isinstance(cls, io.IOBase)"?

Tags: python, file, class, isinstance

It seems that checking `isinstance(..., io.IOBase)` is the 'correct' way to determine if an object is 'file-like'.

However, when defining my own file-like class, it doesn't seem to work:

```python
import io

class file_like():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def write(self, line):
        print("Written:", line)

    def close(self):
        pass

    def flush(self):
        pass

print(isinstance(file_like(), io.IOBase))
# Prints 'False'
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `isinstance(something, io.IOBase)` only checks if `something` is an instance of an `io.IOBase` or a class derived from it — so I don't understand where you got the mistaken idea that it's the "correct" way to determine if an object is "file-like".

A different way to do it is with an *Abstract Base Class*. Python has a number of [built-in ones](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=collections%20abstract%20base%20classes), but currently doesn't have one for "file-like" that could used with `isinstance()`. However you can define your own by using the `abc` module as outlined in [PEP 3119](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#id34).

[The Python Module of the Week](http://pymotw.com/2) webiste has a [good explanation](http://pymotw.com/2/abc) of using the `abc` module to do things like as this. And this highly rated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306222/355230) to the question [Correct way to detect sequence parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305359/correct-way-to-detect-sequence-parameter) shows a similar way of defining your own ABC.

To illustrate applying it to your case, you could define an ABC like this with all its methods abstract — thereby forcing derived classes to define all of them in order to be instantiated:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class ABCFileLike(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self): pass

    @abstractmethod
    def write(self, line): pass

    @abstractmethod
    def close(self): pass

    @abstractmethod
    def flush(self): pass
```

You could then derive your own concrete classes from it, making sure to supply implementations of all the abstract methods. (If you don't define them all, then a `TypeError` will be be raised if any attempts are made to instantiate it.)

```
class FileLike(ABCFileLike):
    """ Concrete implementation of a file-like class.
        (Meaning all the abstract methods have an implementation.)
    """
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def write(self, line):
        print("Written:", line)

    def close(self):
        pass

    def flush(self):
        pass

print(isinstance(FileLike(), ABCFileLike))  # -> True
```

You can even add existing classes to it by registering them with the new metaclass:

```
import io

print(isinstance(io.IOBase(), ABCFileLike))  # -> False

ABCFileLike.register(io.IOBase)
print(isinstance(io.IOBase(), ABCFileLike))  # -> True
```

Answer (score 2):

`isinstance(obj, some_class)` just iterates up obj's inheritance chain, looking for `some_class`. Thus `isinstance(file_like, io.IOBase)`, will be false, as your `file_like` class doesn't have `io.IOBase` in its ancestry. `file_like` doesn't designate an explicit parent, hence it implicitly inherits only from `object`. That's the only class - besides `file_like` itself - that will test positive for a `file_like` instance with `isinstance()`.

What you are doing in `file_like` is defining the methods expected on a file-like object while not inheriting from any particular "file-like" class. This approach is called [duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and it has many merits in dynamic languages, although it's more popular in others (e.g. Ruby) than Python. Still, if whatever you're providing your `file_like` instance to follows duck-typing, it should work, provided your `file_like` does in fact "quack like a file", i.e. behaves sufficiently like a file to not cause errors upon usage at the receiving end.

Of course, if the receiving end is not following duck-typing, for example tries to check types by `isinstance()` as you do here, this approach will fail.

Finally, a small stylistic nit: don't put empty parens on a class if it doesn't inherit anything explicitly. They are redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It cleared up many of my questions. Thanks also for the style note, I believe it's a carryover from functions which requires parens. I'll take note of it